# Where will a robot be after infinite steps, if its first step is 5 to the right, then turn with an angle of 20° and its next step is 70% of the last?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

A robot's first step is 5 to the right, then it turns with an angle of $20°$ and its next step is $70\%$ of the length of the last. Where will the robot be after infinitely many steps?

Calculation:
\begin{align}
&z = 0,7(\cos(20°) + i\sin(20°))\\
&z_\infty  = \frac{5}{1 - z} = 9.810 + 6.863i\\
& (9.810,6.863)\\
\end{align}
But I don't get step 2. Can anyone explain this step to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty az^k=\frac{a}{1-z}.$$

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is that I don't really get why that is equal to each other.

Comment: The second equality sign is not related to the previous expression. Instead something like $z_\infty$ shall be on the LHS and a point after "$z = 0,7(cos20 + isin20)$".

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand why $z_\infty=\frac{5}{1-z}$

Comment: Because it is the sum of geometrical progression (see the answer).

Comment: But what is the proof of that? I don't want to just memorise it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series

Comment: $$S_n = 1 + r + r^2 + \cdots + r^n$$ $$rS_n = r + r^2 + r^3 + \cdots + r^{n+1}$$ Now subtract these two, get $S_n$ on one side, and take the limit as $n\to\infty$ (assuming $|r|<1$).